# c# Windows form application error on comboBox

Tags: c#

I am new to c# windows form app. Here is my question:
I created a comboBox in a form, and add items to this comboBox as below:

```
foreach (string name in seqNames)
{

    comboBox.items.add(name);
}
```

and later check if any comboBox item is selected by

```
if (comboBox.selectedItem.toString().length > 0)
{
      blabla;
}
```

but when I run it, without select any item in this combo box, I got an error : 
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Anyone help me out? Please.....
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make a reference to `comboBox.SelectedItem` and no item is selected, then the selected item is `null` and you can't do `null.ToString()`.

Instead try testing the selected item like this:

```
if (comboBox.SelectedItem != null)
{
      blabla;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`SelectedItem` is returning null (i.e., no item is selected), and attempting to call a method on `null` will result in an exception.  Andrew has already noted this (+1 Andrew), but I thought I would add that you may benefit from setting the `DropDownStyle` property to `ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList`.

If you don't want your users typing into it and you always want some item selected this is a better approach, and in that case you can count on `SelectedItem` never being null (assuming items cannot be removed from the `ComboBox` and you always initialize it with at least one item.)